# Move-CSUser bulk move prompt after 10-15 users

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

I am wanting to migrate users from SfB 2015 CU 11 to SkypeOnline/Teams

I connect once and create a session successfully

Here is my Move command which I then run in a loop for a batch of users

`Move-CsUser -Identity $user -Target sipfed.online.lync.com -Credential $creds -HostedMigrationOverrideUrl $url -ProxyPool $SfbPool -DomainController $DCName -ErrorAction Stop -UseOAuth -Confirm:$False`

However after moving 10-15 users, I get a OAuth Microsoft window come up that the account executing the migration was not able to be used. And if I wait for a little while (2-3 mins) and try again it works again after that. Then the cycle repeats. Any idea why this may be happening? Is it throttling activity?

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Comment: Could indeed be throttling. Does `Move-CsUser` give any indication of what happens in the background if you add `-Verbose`?

Comment: I have not tried adding verbose. Unfortunately, I dont have a batch ready to test with because users have to be notified and communicated to which makes that difficult to test until the its really go-time. Are there any references on the web regarding the throttling? One question I have is whether the same throttling applies if I drop the UseOAuth switch and go the Legacy authentication route?

Comment: I haven't worked with Teams/Skype/UCS for a long time, so I can't answer that last one (although I suspect migrating users to Teams without OAuth is _not_ supported). Microsoft [publishes some documentation on throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#what-happens-when-throttling-occurs), but since you never see the raw API response I don't think it'll be of much use to you :-/ You might want to write your batches to file and then use the `Move-CsUser -UserList` parameter set instead of doing one user at a time (might help with your problem)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this is the case, but this sounds like the remote session module timeout I was plagued with in my Exchange online remote sessions.

If you use "Import-PSSession" in your script, this could very well be the problem.

To resolve that timeout issue, you export your PS session to your local modules path, and then import the module into your script. You don't need to use Import-PSSession after that, and since you're using a local module, it doesn't timeout, and you're not prompted for creds again.

Here's the command I used to export my exchange session to a local path.

```
Export-PsSession -session $Session -CommandName get-*, add-*, enable-*, new-* -outputModule “$path\Exchange” -encoding ASCII -AllowClobber -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same when moving users. My findings were, that if I choose to sign in in the prompt with another account, but use the same email, script continues to run, however asks for account input. I think optional parameter that is presented "-TenantAdminUserName" can do the trick.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/move-csuser?view=skype-ps

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fixed with a Wait between each Move:
Start-Sleep -s 45